# Is this proof of the fact that there are only two groups of order $6$ valid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I know that this is a well known problem, but I couldn't find this specific proof for it and I want to make sure that it is correct.
Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group of order $6$. From Cauchy's theorem we know that there are $a, b \in G$ such that $\operatorname{ord}a=2$ and $\operatorname{ord}b=3$.
If $ab=ba$, then we have that $\operatorname{ord}(ab)=6$ and it follows that $G$ is cyclic, so it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_6, +)$.
If $ab\ne ba$, we have that $G=\{e,a,b,ab,ba,b^2\}$.
Let $\sigma=(12)$ and $\tau=(132)$. Consider the function $f:G \to S_3$, $f(a)=\sigma, f(b)=\tau, f(b^2)=\tau^2, f(ab)=\sigma \tau, f(ba)=\tau \sigma, f(e)=e'$, where I denoted the identical permutation by $e'$. From $f$'s definition we may see that it is a homomorphism and since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ generate $S_3$ we may also conclude that $f$ is bijective, so it is an isomorphism and we are done.
I believe that this proof is all right, but I also want to see your opinion. Could I have skipped defining the isomorphism since $G=<a,b>$ and $S_3=<\sigma, \tau>$ and these generators have the same orders in their respective groups?

Comment: $G=\{e,a,b,ab,ba,b^2\}$ could be recognized as a [dihedral group](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DihedralGroupD3.html)

Comment: For an alternative proof, see **Theorem 7.3** of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"* (with $p=3$).

Comment: You need to make sure the relations among the generators are respected.  Having generators of the same order is not sufficient.

Comment: In the $ab \neq ba$ case, why do you believe you have a complete list of elements of $G$?  For instance, you include both length-two words on $a$ and $b$: $ab$, and $ba$, but only consider including the first of $b^2$, $aba$, $ab^2$, $bab$, and $b^2a$.  Why can the sixth element not be one of the other products on this list (... or why is taking $b^2$ as the sixth element equivalent to picking any other word in the free group on $a$ and $b$ as the sixth element)?

Comment: @EricTowers Because $\operatorname{ord}G=6$, the other combinations you mention have to be equal to one of these $6$ elements that I chose because they were the easiest to pick.

Comment: @ChemistryGeek : Not quite.  You know that if we write down seven words, at least two of them are the same element of $G$.  You **have not** shown that all six words you write are distinct elements.

Comment: You have built up two nonisomorphic groups (and this irrespective of the second being isomorphic to $S_3$), and that's ok (though see Eric's comment). Rather, I'm missing where in your proof is clearly ruled out any possibile "third option".

Comment: @EricTowers I agree with you, but I think that it is quite easy to see that they are distinct elements. However, you are right, I should have added that for rigour.

Comment: @user750041 It is kind of obvious that any possible third option is ruled out. If $ab=ba$, then the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_6$. If $ab\ne ba$, then the group is isomorphic to $S_3$. Since this covers everything, we are done.

Comment: Right, I was overthinking.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct. The last sentence is wrong. There are (infinitely) many finite (simple) groups generated by two elements of orders $2,3$. For example all groups $\mathrm{PSL}(2,p)$ are such.

Answer (score 0):

Let G be an abelian group of of order 6, then G contains an element say a of order 2 and an element say b of order 3 by cauchy's theorem.  Therefore order of ab will be 6 and G will be a cyclic group and any  finite cyclic group is unique. Now if G is nonabelian of order 6=2.3 and here 2 divides  (3-1)=2, so G is a unique group of order 6.